# Typescript cannot install google.maps with typings in ionic2

Tags: typescript

```
typings install google.maps --save
```

the following also gives the same error

```
typings install google.maps --ambient
typings install google.maps --global
```

> typings ERR! message Unable to find "google.maps" ("npm") in the
> registry. Did you want to try searching another source? Also, if you
> want contribute these typings, please help us:
> github.com/typings/registry typings ERR! caused by
> https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/google.maps/versions/latest
> responded with 404, expected it to equal 200
>
> typings ERR! cwd /Users/jeswinjames24/Work/xyz typings ERR! system
> Darwin 15.3.0 typings ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node"
> "/usr/local/bin/typings" "install" "google.maps" "--save" typings ERR!
> node -v v4.3.1 typings ERR! typings -v 1.0.3
>
> typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at: typings
> ERR!   github.com/typings/typings/issues MacBook-Pro:xyzjeswinjames24$
> npm install google-maps xyz@ /Users/jeswinjames24/Work/xyz

Answer (score 4):

This was changed in [typings 1.0.0](https://github.com/typings/typings/releases/tag/v1.0.0) where `--ambient` was renamed to `--global`.

You'll also need to explicitly state the source to install from to over-ride the default (which is npm).  Looks like you'll need to install the google-maps type definitions from the DefinitelyTyped (dt) source:

```
[stewart@localhost cenode]$ typings search google-maps
Viewing 2 of 2

NAME                   SOURCE HOMEPAGE                                                                       DESCRIPTION VERSIONS UPDATED                 
google-maps            dt     https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps                                                  1        2015-12-03T17:40:25.000Z
google.maps.infobubble dt     http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/src/             1        2016-03-17T12:06:54.000Z
```

So:

`typings install dt~google-maps --global`

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

```
typings install github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/googlemaps/google.maps.d.ts --global --save
```

Since none of the above methods worked for me, I installed Google Maps TypeScript definitions directly from GitHub!

Answer (score 1):

To make your application find your libraries that you installed with typings, you need to make the compiler reach the typings and compiling them. to do that, include typings path ("typings/*.d.ts") in your tsconfig.json

[link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2865)

I tested the following steps on my ionic 2 project and it is works perfectly:

1- install **typings** globally :

```js
npm install typings --global
```

2- install google.maps via typings

```js
typings install dt~google.maps --global --save
```

3- open tsconfig.json and add **"typings/*.d.ts"** to your "include" array as shown below (tsconfig.json).

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "typings/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check this out:-

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps